# Tess4j Image reading

Tags: ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I am using tess4j api for reading an image for numerics.

**code as below:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
       final File imageFile = new File("C:\\Users\\goku\\Desktop\\myimage.png");
        System.out.println("Image found");
       final ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
        instance.setTessVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
        instance.setDatapath("C:\\Users\\goku\\Downloads\\Tess4J"); 
        instance.setLanguage("eng");
        String result;
        try {
            result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (TesseractException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       

}
```

Image attached.
[image: 1]

The program is reading the numerics as wrong. Not  able to find the issue.

**output:**

1  1 3 251

regards,
Vasu

Answer (score 0):

Rescaling the image to 300 DPI would get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to properly edit image with [im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net) (imagemagick) so it can be read with [tess4j](https://github.com/nguyenq/tess4j) (tesseract):

```
private static File processImage(File img) throws IOException {
    File newImg = File.createTempFile("asdf", ".png");

    ImageMagickCmd cmd = new ImageMagickCmd("convert");
    IMOperation op = new IMOperation();

    op.addImage(img.getAbsolutePath());
    op.strip().resample(300).colorspace("gray").autoLevel().threshold(35000).type("bilevel").depth(8).trim();
    op.addImage(newImg.getAbsolutePath());
    cmd.run(op);

    return newImg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be the trained data. I have used the trained data from the tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v4.1.0.20190314.exe Windows binary, found at https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/, with the datapath set as below

```
instance.setDatapath("C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata");
```

I do get a warning about the resolution, but the result is correct:
471871882819